# How to call a shiny app from a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, tabitem

I want to build a dashboard. And each tab-item will call one shiny app. 
I see there are some recommendations online including module and iframe.

However, this will not work in my current framework. My dashboardbody use uioutput.

```
body <- dashboardBody(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
        tags$head(tags$link (rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")),
        uiOutput("sideTabs"))
```

So in my server.R. I write code like this:

`output$sideTabs <- renderUI({
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="dashboard",h2("adsf")),
      tabItem(tabName="gold",source(file.path("apps", "xxx", "ui.R"), local = TRUE)$value)
            )`

But it doesn't work. For the small app, I use the sample code from shiny gallery (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html).

Anyone can provide some ideas? I am confused about the problem for days.

Comment: A single R session can host at most one Shiny app at a time. There's just one server() function running. Do you just want to include HTML elements from different files?

Comment: Why create multiple shiny apps, just `source()` different codes on tabs in single shiny app.